# How do you update vcperf in a visual studio installation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The vcperf package in Visual Studio 2019 16.11.26 is version 2.0.20102101

In the current v2.2 there is a new-ish option to run profiling without administrative privileges.

I cannot figure out how to detail instructions for IT to update vcperf to the latest version so that I can run it without admin.

The visual studio installer / modify mode doesn't offer anything that I was able to find.

My current fallback is cloning the repository from here: https://github.com/microsoft/vcperf and compiling it myself but I am unsure if there was a better option, so I am leaving this question here.